# pm2 restart all keeps restarting again and again when run from script

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, pm2

I have a script(bash) which monitors pm2 memory usage and restarts the process if pm2 process takes memory more than 2 GB. But when i run the command (pm2 restart all) from the script, all processes in pm2 keep restarting again and again.

I am running this script via a crontab.

I want to be able to successfully restart all apps without continous restart.

Answer (score 1):

pm2 already has an option for max memory which is `max_memory_restart: "3G"` which will restart the process if it's taking more than `3G` for example.

Source: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/process-management/#max-memory-restart

Comment: The script is to manage the PM2 god daemon itself not the child process that the God daemon runs. The child processes are Working fine.